# NSImage rotation using block code blurry on non-retina

Tags: macos, retina-display, core-image, image-rotation, nsimage

I am using the following function to rotate an NSImage. It uses block code in order to render properly on retina. The problem now is that it renders blurry on non-retina screens.

I tried checking for a retina display [NSWindow backingScaleFactor] and then using a non-block method on non-retina displays, but the is a case in which it doesn't work - if the user has a retina Mac but is displaying to an external non-retina display, the check backingScaleFactor reports a retina screen. I then found this document on Apple's developer site:

**APIs for Supporting High Resolution**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsAnimation/Conceptual/HighResolutionOSX/APIs/APIs.html

But it's frankly inscrutable. How can the following function be modified to not blur on non-retina displays?

```
- (NSImage *)imageRotatedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees {
// calculate the bounds for the rotated image
NSRect imageBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [self size]};
NSBezierPath *boundsPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageBounds];
NSAffineTransform *transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];

[transform rotateByDegrees:degrees];
[boundsPath transformUsingAffineTransform:transform];

NSRect rotatedBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [boundsPath bounds].size};

// center the image within the rotated bounds
imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth (imageBounds) / 2);
imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight (imageBounds) / 2);

NSImage *rotatedImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:rotatedBounds.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:^BOOL (NSRect dstRect) {
    // set up the rotation transform
    NSAffineTransform *transform=[NSAffineTransform transform];
    [transform translateXBy:+(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:+(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
    [transform rotateByDegrees:degrees];
    [transform translateXBy:-(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:-(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];

    // draw the original image, rotated, into the new image
    [transform concat];
    [self drawInRect:imageBounds fromRect:NSZeroRect operation:NSCompositeCopy fraction:1.0];
    return YES;
}];

return rotatedImage;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this

- (NSImage*)rotateImagedByDegrees:(CGFloat)degrees  Image:(NSImage *)sourceImage
  {

  ```
  NSImage *image = sourceImage;

  if (degrees == 0)
  {
      return image;
  }
  else
  {

      NSRect imageBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [sourceImage size]};
      NSSize rotatedSize = NSMakeSize(sourceImage.size.height, sourceImage.size.width) ;
      NSImage* rotatedImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:rotatedSize] ;

      NSBezierPath* boundsPath = [NSBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:imageBounds];
      NSAffineTransform* transform = [NSAffineTransform transform];
      [transform rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];
      [boundsPath transformUsingAffineTransform:transform];
      NSRect rotatedBounds = {NSZeroPoint, [boundsPath bounds].size};
      imageBounds.origin.x = NSMidX(rotatedBounds) - (NSWidth(imageBounds) / 2);
      imageBounds.origin.y = NSMidY(rotatedBounds) - (NSHeight(imageBounds) / 2);

      rotatedImage = [NSImage imageWithSize:rotatedBounds.size flipped:NO drawingHandler:NO];

      NSAffineTransform* transform1 = [NSAffineTransform transform];
      [transform1 translateXBy:+(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:+(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
      [transform1 rotateByDegrees:-1.0 * degrees];
      [transform1 translateXBy:-(NSWidth(rotatedBounds) / 2) yBy:-(NSHeight(rotatedBounds) / 2)];
      [rotatedImage lockFocus] ;
      [transform1 concat] ;

      [sourceImage drawInRect:imageBounds
                     fromRect:NSMakeRect(0.0, 0.0, [sourceImage size].width, [sourceImage size].height)
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceOver fraction:1.0];

      [rotatedImage unlockFocus] ;
      return rotatedImage;
  ```

  }
  }